# you never learned, did you? or You never learn, did you?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning, word-difference

I would like to ask which of the sentences or questions above is correct or what could be the best correction? The message that I would like to convey is that to improve a behavior as a result of gaining greater experience or knowledge of something.

Comment: My option, "**You never learn, do you?**"

Answer (score 1):

The first is grammatically correct. The second has a problem in that the tense of the tag question doesn't match the main sentence. It should be "You never learn, do you?"

Then the only difference is one of tense: The first is past tense. It concerns a matter in the past:

> (on discovering a poor man from a slum can't read) "I understand why you can't read. *You never learned, did you?* You never went to school?"

The second is present tense, and concerns facts that are unchanging:

> (Mother, on finding her son is playing games instead of studying) "I tell you everyday that you need to study, but *you never learn, do you?* You never listen to what anybody tells you."

The second sentence implies criticism.